# Apodization Mask for Fast Fourier Transforms in Python

Tags: python, scikit-image

I need to do a Fourier transform of a map in Python. Fast Fourier Transforms expect periodic boundary conditions, but the input map is not periodic. So I need to apply an input filter/weight slowly tapering the map toward zero at the edges. Are there libraries for doing this in python?

Comment: Something like np.hanning, np.hamming, np.bartlett, np.blackman, np.kaiser (where np is numpy)?

Answer (score 2):

My favorite function to apodize a map is the generalized Gaussian (also called '[Super-Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#Higher-order_Gaussian_or_super-Gaussian_function)' which is a Gaussian whose exponent is raised to a power P.  By setting P to, say, 4 or 6 you get a flat-top pulse which falls off smoothly, which is good for FFT applications where sharp edges always create ripples in conjugate space.

The generalized Gaussian is available on Scipy. Here is a minimal code (Python 3) to apodize a 2D array with a generalized Gaussian. As noted in previous comments, there are dozens of functions which would work just as well.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import general_gaussian

# A 128x128 array
array =  np.random.rand(128,128)
# Define a general Gaussian in 2D as outer product of the function with itself
window = np.outer(general_gaussian(128,6,50),general_gaussian(128,6,50))
# Multiply
ap_array = window*array
```

Answer (score 1):

Such tapering is often referred to as a "[window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function)".

Scipy has many [window functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html#window-functions).

You can use [numpy.expand_dims](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) to create the 2D window you want.

Regarding Stefan's comment, apparently the numpy team thinks that including more [than arrays was a mistake](https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/faq.html#what-is-the-difference-between-numpy-and-scipy). I would stick to using scipy for signal processing. Watch out, as they moved quite a bit of functions around in their 1.0 release so older documentation is, well, quite old.

As a final note: a "filter" is typically reserved for multiplications you apply in the **Frequency domain,** not spatial domain.